Multiple labels within left/right scaling?
\[
\begin{subequations}

\left.

\begin{align}

\frac{d}{dt}\omega_{1} & = \frac{I_{2} - I_{3}}{I_1} \omega_{2}\omega_{3}
\label{eq:1a}\\

\frac{d}{dt}\omega_{2} & = \frac{I_{1} - I_{3}}{I_2} \omega_{1}\omega_{3}
\label{eq:1b}\\

\frac{d}{dt}\omega_{3} & = \frac{I_{2} - I_{1}}{I_3} \omega_{2}\omega_{1}
\label{eq:1c}

\end{align}

\right\} I_{1} > I_{2} > I_{3}

\end{subequations}
\]

It won't let me create a label for each equation within this system, is there a way around this? I'd like to refer to specific equations within the system, and not the entire system as a whole. I'd appreciate any help as I'm new to latex and can't really find this issue talked about anywhere.

Welcome to TeX.SE.

Welcome to TSE. Please post a Minimal Working Example, starting with \documentclass and ending with \end{document}, instead of a code snippet.

Something like this?

I can't say that this is particularly easy to take in. Do you really have to place I_{1} > I_{2} > I_{3} to the right of the equations instead of, say, in a half-sentence above or below the equations?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'subequations' and 'align' environments

\begin{document}
\[
\left.
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}\omega_{1} & = \frac{I_{2} - I_{3}}{I_1} \omega_{2}\omega_{3}
   \label{eq:1a}\\
\frac{d}{dt}\omega_{2} & = \frac{I_{1} - I_{3}}{I_2} \omega_{1}\omega_{3}
   \label{eq:1b}\\
\frac{d}{dt}\omega_{3} & = \frac{I_{2} - I_{1}}{I_3} \omega_{2}\omega_{1}
   \label{eq:1c}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
\end{minipage}
\right\}
\quad
I_{1} > I_{2} > I_{3} \notag
\]
\end{document}


It’s not entirely necessary, but I was wondering how it could be done (if at all). Thank you!
